# Display time (hours:minutes (am/pm)) in php based on locale

Tags: php, datetime

I want to display time based on the user's locale without the seconds and with pm or am in case of non 24 hour format. I set the locale using setlocale() function from PHP.

So I want to achieve this:

**03:59 PM or 15:59**

The closest solution I could find is:

```
strftime('%X', time());
```

which will display

**03:59:16 or 15:59:16**

Ofcourse I could remove the seconds from that result, but then I still have the problem that there is no AM/PM based on user's locale.

Any suggestions on how I could achieve this in a nice way?

Comment: http://uk1.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Comment: `strftime('%I:%M %p');`

Answer (score 2):

See the format table here http://php.net/strftime

```php
strftime('%I:%M %p');
```

[**Demo**](https://eval.in/115567)

Comment: This doesn't solve my problem. This will only show it in am/pm format, not in 24 hour format. It should pick the correct vrsion based on the locale I set in setlocale()

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
strftime('%I:%M %p');
```

For more information, check the [documentation](https://www.php.net/strftime).

Comment: Function [`strftime()`](http://php.net/strftime) doesn't have same format as function `date()`. `%a` is an abbreviated textual representation of the day: `Sun through Sat`.

Comment: Now you have same answer as my ;)

Comment: This only returns the time in 12 hour format. In case the user prefers 24 hour format it should display that. (based on locale)

Answer (score 0):

Try using explode and ltrim:

```
$time = strftime('%X',time());
$parts = explode(':',$time);
$parts[2] = ltrim($parts[2],'0');
$formatted = ltrim($parts[0].':'.$parts[1].' '.$parts[2],'0');
```

strftime('%X',time()) will include AM or PM if the locale indicates it.